# Crashlytics distribution for app with multiple flavors

Tags: android, gradle, crashlytics

I'm trying to use crashlytics distribution for android app with multiple flavors. 
Everything worked fine when there were no flavors, but as soon as I've added two flavors I'm receiving

```
*'Task 'crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease' not found in root project'*
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Ohh, I did miss something..
Don't forget to add your flavor name to:

```
crashlyticsUploadDistribution<FLAVOR>Release
```

Comment: I have the same issue. However this solution is not working for me. I have posted the question with my configuration http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27519482/automatic-beta-releases-with-crashlytics. Appreciate if you could shed some light.

Comment: @HasaniK you can try 'gradle tasks --all' to see all the available tasks. I had typo mistakes in my case

Comment: Thanks for your response.. When I run 'gradle tasks -all' I dont see any tasks with crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease. Could this be a problem with configuration of crashlytics in my project.

Comment: @Hasanik there are tasks based on your flavours and buildTypes, ex `crashlyticsUploadDistributionDevStaging` where `dev` is `flavour` and `Staging` is `buildType`

Comment: where crashlyticsUploadDistribution shouldbe placed ?