# Automatic Beta Releases with crashlytics

Tags: gradle, crashlytics

My android application has a Library which includes 'crashlytics.start()'. I have only set Crashlytics.jar as a dependency for the Library project. Builds are successful.

I have multiple flavors configured in app> build.gradle file as well.

Given that one of my builds flavors are called "production", I have the following configuration in my app> build.gradle file

```
   buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13+'

    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'


repositories {
    mavenCentral()

}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.6"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            ext.enableCrashlytics=true
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            ext.betaDistributionEmails="email" 
            ext.betaDistributionReleaseNotes='Testing automatic release.Ignore this version'

        }

        debug{
            ext.enableCrashlytics=true
            runProguard false

        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        production {
            applicationId "com.test.testapp"
        }

        staging {
            applicationId "com.test.testapp.staging"
        }

        preprod {
            applicationId "ccom.test.testapp.preprod"
        }

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
    compile project(':lib1')
    compile project(':lib2')

}
```

I use following command to upload the built 'production 'flavor to crashlytics

`assembleproductionRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionproductionRelease`

However I get the following error

```
Task 'crashlyticsUploadDistributionproductionRelease' not found in root project
```

This looks similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27383732/crashlytics-distribution-for-app-with-multiple-flavors) however the solution is not working for me. There for posting with details.

NOTE: I have added a local crashlytics.jar when including crashlytics dependency. Since including the hosted crashlytics dependency had issues when compiling the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have working configuration in my environment, so will just share gradle.build pieces that are different:
1. Buildscript

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.12.+'
    } 
}
```

2. Don't forget to apply plugin

> apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

3. Repositories

> ```
> repositories {
>         mavenCentral()
>         maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
>     }
> ```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks! think the problem was missing  classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+' and the plugin ( Out of the many that I tried)

Comment: for me it doesnt work, com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+ except for the latest, continues to have the same error.
With version 1.16 there are tons of "unable to resolve dependency for.."