# TravisCI, building with Gradle and deploying with Crashlytics

Tags: android, gradle, travis-ci, crashlytics

I've successfully deployed to Crashlytics from TravisCI with iOS, and now I'm tackling our Android project.

I've seen this link: http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/388925-beta-distributions-with-gradle

and also this stackoverflow post: [Automatic Beta Releases with crashlytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27519482/automatic-beta-releases-with-crashlytics)

but I am not using any flavours (yet) and I am getting the same error:

```
Task 'crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease' not found in root project 'FezzeeAndroid'.
```

Here's my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.13.0'
    } 
}
```

apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }
}

Here is my .travis.yml

```
language: android
android:
  components:
    - android-21
    - build-tools-21.1.2
```

before_install:

# for gradle output style
  - export TERM=dumb

# environment info
  - ./gradlew -v
  - uname -a

# Let's try to build...
script: 
    - ./gradlew tasks --all
    - ./gradlew --stacktrace assembleRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease

I should note that ./gradlew tasks --all

```
./gradlew tasks --all
```

does not reveal a task named

```
crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my build.gradle for crashlytics and it works

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
    classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'

repositories {
   maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}

android {
   compileSdkVersion 21
   buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

   defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.android....."
      minSdkVersion 11
      targetSdkVersion 21
      compileOptions {
          sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
          targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    testApplicationId "com.android.......test"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),     'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
 }
```

Comment: Your solution worked, and then I found this, after MUCH searching.
https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/integrate

This is also a great resource https://github.com/plastiv/CrashlyticsDemo